# Authorization AJAX requests in Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, csrf

We are running a website with a standard user authentication made in Laravel framework. Now we have to create React application that will be available only for authenticated users and that has to communicate with Laravel backend to get some data.

My question is simple - is it enough to protect AJAX requests called by React by attaching Laravel CSRF token to each request or should we implement some token mechanism like JWT etc? Thanks!

Comment: read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

Comment: @SalmanZafar Thanks for your answer, I know Laravel Passport. My question was if we have to implement Laravel Passport or similar token based mechanism or it's enough to protect requests with CSRF token since we don't plan to create mobile app in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be to go with the jwt mechanism if you are creating a separate react app and separate  backend app . By doing so if you decided to create the mobile app in future for the projectyou wouldn't have to bother that much

Comment: Thank you for answer Ashok! That's what I thought. We don't plan to create mobile app in the future.